# Неправильное расположение карты

Tags: wordpress

Снова проблема:

Карта (находится в самом низу), отображается некорректно. Слева есть отступ.
Карта создана с помощью конструктора яндекс карты.

Код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A0a67e5cf1a66b13987cb70b461c791d21db760e8d0d772f108e214fd683f71b1&width=1550&height=339&lang=ru_RU&scroll=true"></script>
```

Нужно, чтобы карта заполняла все пространство, как справа, так и слева не должно быть белого пространства.

Как можно исправить?

Comment: ссылка на сайт: http://gelios-pnz.ru

Answer (score 0):

У вас блок с картой находится в блоке с классом `.container`.

Вынесите его отдельно, чтобы он не имел отступов.

А дальше либо в настройках карты укажите ширину - параметр `width` в вашем коде подключения, либо через CSS:

```
#ymaps1608882022364483168{
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Никуда она не может вынести, у неё там тема со своим конструктором.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в конец файла http://gelios-pnz.ru/wp-content/themes/twinkle/style.css следующий css-код:

```
#twinkle_maps_section > .container > ymaps {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

Comment: бред получается, неверно код оформлен

Comment: Поясните. Код css, что я привёл в ответе, валидный и рабочий,  я проверил его в браузере на сайте. Бред, видимо, потому, что вы не там его используете.

Comment: я полностью скопировала код, а у меня он отображается очень криво

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять осмысленные комментарии. Куда скопировали? Что значит - криво?

Comment: Ну то, что вы творите, никак копированием назвать нельзя. В файл blue.css вы вставили `#twinkle_maps_section ymaps {
   width=100%!important;
  height=500
    
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
`

Это никак не похоже на то, что я писал, и вообще поперёк синтаксиса css.

Comment: Я поправил свой ответ, но бога ради, скопируйте его как есть в тот файл, что я указал.

Comment: Вот как выглядит ваша карта с поправленным файлом style.css - всё ровно так, как вы хотите: https://prnt.sc/wbmco0

Comment: сейчас снова добавила ваш код, теперь все заработало как нужно!
спасибо большое

Comment: все отлично, только теперь что-то текст съехал((

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.